# Handling non ASCII characters with principals in CQ5 REST interface

Tags: rest, encoding, utf-8, aem

We are managing CQ5 groups using the REST interface. To add a user we do

```
POST http://$host:$port/home/groups/t/test_group.rw.html
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

addMembers:my_principal_name
```

which works as expected as long as the the name contains ASCII characters only.

We tried to use latin 1 (ISO-8859-1). For example for a principal name `ü`:

```
POST http://$host:$port/home/groups/t/test_group.rw.html
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

addMembers:%FC
```

In this case no  error is generated but the principal is not added.

Our workaround is to use UTF-8 and URL-encode it **twice**. `ü` is `C3BC`, URL-encoded it becomes `%C3%BC` and encoded another time `%25C3%25BC`

Summarizing, to add a member `ü` we have to submit

```
POST http://$host:$port/home/groups/t/test_group.rw.html
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

addMembers:%25C3%25BC
```

which works as expected.

Is this a bug or the API really requires to send UTF-8-encoded strings URL encoded twice?

**Edit** I tried with the additional `_charset_` parameter

```
telnet ******** 8000
Trying ********...
Connected to ********.
Escape character is '^]'.
POST /home/groups/nethz/lz/06065.rw.html HTTP/1.1
Host: *********:8000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic ****************=
_charset_=UTF-8&addMembers=aaaa_testgr%C3%BCppli

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Server: Day-Servlet-Engine/4.1.44 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 10:50:19 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

4f6
<html>
<head>
    <title>Content modified /home/groups/nethz/lz/06065</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <h1>Content modified /home/groups/nethz/lz/06065</h1>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td><div id="Status">200</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message</td>
                <td><div id="Message">OK</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td><a href="" id="Location"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Parent Location</td>
                <td><a href="" id="ParentLocation"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Path</td>
                <td><div id="Path">/home/groups/nethz/lz/06065</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Referer</td>
                <td><a href="" id="Referer"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ChangeLog</td>
                <td><div id="ChangeLog">&lt;pre&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;</div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><a href="">Go Back</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Modified Resource</a></p>
    <p><a href="">Parent of Modified Resource</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

We are getting a status 200 answer, but the subgroup `aaaa_testgrüppli` (`aaa_testgr%C3%BCppli`) is not inserted in `/home/groups/nethz/lz/06065`

Answer (score 1):

Sling [gets request encoding](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/request-parameters.html#character-encoding) from the `_charset_` POST parameter. `ISO-8859-1` is a fallback value. Try setting this parameter to `UTF-8`.

Comment: This is maybe true for forms, but not for the Authorizable Servlet. The charset parameter is always ignored.

Comment: I believe it isn't ignored. It is implemented in the [`ParameterSupport`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.engine/2.2.8/org/apache/sling/engine/impl/parameters/ParameterSupport.java#56) class, which is a part of the `SlingMainServlet`, which is responsible for handling all servlet requests, including requests to the `AuthorizableServlet`. The document I've linked in the answer is also related to the general servlet requests handling rather than `SlingPostServlet`.

Comment: @TomekRękawek I added an additional test with the additional parameter. Still no effect...